# Does the background color affect the frame rate in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, performance, animation, canvas

Sounds bizarre (to me at least) but if I color the canvas totally white before each frame of an animation (with a `fillRect` call) the frame rate of the subsequent animation is much higher. This is even with the newer alpha: flag having been specified.

Strangely (also) if I only cover some of the canvas white I then get a bad frame rate. Presumably by covering the whole canvas some optimisation is going on. Is that correct?

Comment: Oops - no - HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suspect your presumption is correct.**

The GPU is drawing your canvas using an array of pixel colors.

If all those colors are the same (eg, white) the GPU can simply floodfill that array with r,g,b,a values of all 255. (==fast!)

If some of the colors are different (eg, a white rect but keeping other previous drawings) the CPU and GPU must work together to calculate which existing pixels to keep and which pixels to change. (==slower).